# WSO2 server is not starting when running multiple servers

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-esb

If I want to ESB and API Manager in the same machine to which server I should set the CARBON_HOME? IF setting CARBON_HOME for one server is enough?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to set CARBON_HOME. You only need to set is JAVA_HOME. When carbon server starts up it automatically assigns it to its path. If you set CARBON_HOME manually you won't be able to run multiple servers on the same machine. If you have already set, remove it.

Answer (score 1):

No need of setting `CARBON_HOME` but you must give different offsets in`WSO2_SERVER_HOME/repository/conf/carbon.xml` in each wso2 server.

```
 <Offset>1</Offset>
```

default value is 0

Comment: I already did it. I was bit confused with setting CARBON_HOME.

Answer (score 1):

CARBON_HOME Term means that your current servers directory.You can think of Just like JAVA_HOME. You can have one server in one machine by changing the port offset in carbon.xml located in HOME/repository/conf/carbon.xml